# colortbl, multicolumn and settototalheight don't work together

Tags: longtable, mathtools, colortbl

I have a script that generates super-complicated tables, which need individual cells with coloured backgrounds. At the moment I'm using my own macro to generate the coloured cells, but I would rather use the much better macros in `colortbl`. However, importing the `colortbl` package causes my latex documents to fail with:

```
$ pdflatex  tbl_example.tex 
! Undefined control sequence.
<template> ...@setup \CT@row@color \CT@cell@color 
                                                  \CT@do@color \endgroup \@t...
l.23 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{}}&&
                                            &\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicol...

?
```

In the MWE below, commenting out either `usepackage{colortbl}`, or the definition of `\blankheight` or the table column causes this document to compile with no errors. What have I done wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newlength{\blankheight}%
\settototalheight{\blankheight}{%
$\begin{array}{rr}%
\scriptstyle{0} \\[-6pt]%
\scriptscriptstyle{0}%
\end{array}%
$%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ll@{\hspace{0cm}}ll@{\hspace{-1cm}}r@{\hspace{0cm}}r@{\hspace{0cm}}r@{\hspace{0cm}}r@{\hspace{0cm}}l@{\hspace{.3cm}}ll@{\hspace{-1cm}}r@{\hspace{0cm}}r@{\hspace{0cm}}rr@{\hspace{0cm}}r}

\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{}}&&&\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column}\\
\endhead
\hline

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you explain the details of what you're trying to achieve, and a minimal compilable code of what you've tried?

Comment: Thanks @Bernad, the code in the question is a minimum example of the problem I'm having, when it compiles the problem will be fixed, if that makes sense. The table headings need to be as they are in the MWE, I need to define `blankheight` and to import `colortbl`. Does that help?

Comment: But your table has no colour command!

Comment: unrelated but `\scriptsyle` doesn't take an argument so I guess they should be  `\scriptstyle 0`

Comment: @Bernard the table doesn't use colour and doesn't use `\blankheight` but that is just an artefact of it being a _minimal_ example. It does give the undefined colortbl command error  if you have the definition of `\blankheight` and not if you do not, as it says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delay the setting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xspace}

\newlength{\blankheight}%

\AtBeginDocument{%
\settototalheight{\blankheight}{%
$\begin{array}{rr}%
\scriptstyle{0} \\[-6pt]%
\scriptscriptstyle{0}%
\end{array}%
$%
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{ll@{\hspace{0cm}}ll@{\hspace{-1cm}}r@{\hspace{0cm}}r@{\hspace{0cm}}r@{\hspace{0cm}}r@{\hspace{0cm}}l@{\hspace{.3cm}}ll@{\hspace{-1cm}}r@{\hspace{0cm}}r@{\hspace{0cm}}rr@{\hspace{0cm}}r}

\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{}}&&&\multicolumn{1}{c}{} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Column}\\
\endhead
\hline

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's clever! I had no idea it was even possible, thanks!